# Can Pao de Queijo, and similar foods, be kosher for Passover?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover

We're planning an "alternative" Passover, and are looking into some nontraditional foods that could be kosher for Passover.  One that came up in discussion was [Pao de Queijo](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/98554/brazilian-cheese-bread-pao-de-queijo/), or Brazillan cheese biscuits. These contain cheese, tapioca flour, and eggs.

Since they have no grain at all in them, and the only leavening is eggs -- not unlike "[passover rolls](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/16158/passover-rolls-i/)" -- it seems like they ought to be permitted.  I didn't see them when I attended a Seder in Brazil, though, although that could have been because that Seder was very German-heritage.

So, would Pao de Queijo be permitted or not?  Does it depend on whether you're Ashkenaz or Sephardic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As always, [CYLOR](https://www.yourdictionary.com/cylor) but the answer would seem to be yes.

Regarding Tapioca, [OUKosher.org writes](https://oukosher.org/passover/articles/kitniyot-custom/):

> Similarly, potatoes and tapioca are not considered kitniyot. Although today, they are turned into starch and are the basis for most Passover cakes and cookies, they are permitted because, historically, the minhag was to accept them.

Also, a popular Kosher baker writes [on her blog](https://thekosherbaker.com/pan-de-queijo-passover-cheese-bread/):

> When **I recently learned that Brazilian cheese bread, pao de queijo, is gluten-free, and made with tapioca flour, which is permitted on Passover**, I cheered at the thought of “bread” and “Passover” married together. Karina herself was intrigued, because she never ate the cheese bread during the holiday. She said, “I’m sure the older generation could never imagine eating anything bread-like during Passover.

One is a reliable source, and the other is more of "heard from someone" bit would seem to be ok.
As there is no kitniyot in them, would be ok for both Sefardim and Ashkenzim.

But again just to be 100% safe- [CYLOR](https://www.yourdictionary.com/cylor)

Comment: Also, definitely make this at home rather than buying it at your local Brazilian bakery, they could very easily mix some wheat flour in for texture's sake (beyond the obvious risk of chametz cross-contamination)

Comment: These seem like they might be ok even for those who don't eat "gebrochts" on pesach, unlike the "Pesach Rolls" mentioned in the question.